# Change date format using NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdateformatter

I want to use date format like this **`2015-08-14`** but unfortunately I am getting this format **`16/11/15`**

Below is the code I have used to get desired output.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];

[dateFormatter setDateStyle:kCFDateFormatterShortStyle];

NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:selectedDate];
```

Can anyone please suggest how to fix this issue?

Comment: And if you remove `[dateFormatter setDateStyle:kCFDateFormatterShortStyle];`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Just remove the line `[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];`

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSString*)stringFromDateWithFormat:(NSString*)formatString{

    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = formatString;
    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *selectedDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:selectedDate];

NSLog(@"formattedDateString = %@", formattedDateString); // Prints 2015-10-15
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];
NSLog(@"date is %@",dateString);
```